# Content type is not available for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, content-type, pnp-powershell

Here is what I did in order to create content type,

1. Connect to content type hub(https://.sharepoint.com/sites/contentTypeHub/) via Connect-PnPOnline
2. Create Content Type with command Add-PnPContentType
3. Navigate to https://.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/
4. Navigate to Site Settings -> Content Types and could not find the content type

Because I couldn't see my content type so I went back to Conte Type Hub to see if its published or not and don't see it's published. Do I have to publish it? If yes is there a way I can publish it via PowerShell?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to publish the content type, and wait for the timer job to kick in, that can take upto 24 Hours. I think it is posible to publish the content type using powershell, however I haven't tested it

Comment: Is there a way I can publish Content Type via PowerShell?